# htaccess RewriteCond all file and folder without .php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

MY htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ first.php
```

It's work good. But I want this condition to not work for .php extention file
like if my url is

```
www.example.com/ or 
www.example.com/index.php or 
www.example.com/admin/page.php 
www.example.com/admin
```

then it's open first.php
And if www.example.com/style.css then open style.css file or if www.example.com/image.jpg then open image.jpg file

Comment: Your current rules will skip all `.php` files because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition. Is that not what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to skip all php files from your Apache rewrite, you should add the following RewriteCond prior to your RewriteRule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
```

This rewrite condition checks if the requested filename *does not* end in ".php".
The complete rule set would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ first.php
```

1. Check if requested filename is not a directory.
2. Check if requested filename is not a file.
3. Check if requested filename does not end in ".php".

This might be helpful, if you want to log attacks against non-existing .php files to your Apache log instead forwarding them to your first.php, e.g. to initiate ban actions via fail2ban. I use a similar setting to secure Wordpress instances from being scanned by script kiddies.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [OR] and your condition to match `.php` after checking on file existing.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ first.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

if you want to rewrite HTML use this

```
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html[NC,L]
```